# How to call php if/else statement if value empty

Tags: magento-1.7, php, magento-1, template, php-5.4

Hopefully a nice simple question to start the day...

In `success.phtml`, I would like to achieve the following using PHP:

```
$_commissionGroupCode = [If $_voucher is empty, echo "DEFAULT". Else echo "VOUCHER"]
```

Below is a snippet of my code so far:

```
$lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId(); 
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId);
$_products = $order->getAllItems();

$_totalData = $order->getData(); 
$_discount = $_totalData['discount_amount'];
$_voucher = $_totalData['coupon_code'];
$_commissionGroupCode = ANSWER GOES HERE
```

You will notice I already have $_voucher to call the voucher code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a PHP only question.

Comment: But it may help others trying to achieve integration between Affiliate Window Services and Magento

Comment: Disagree, this is better for stackoverflow. Nontheless, what about `$_ _commissionGroupCode = empty($_voucher) ? "DEFAULT" : "VOUCHER";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$_commissionGroupCode = (!$_voucher ? "DEFAULT" : "VOUCHER");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in one line with a ternary operator

```
$_commissionGroupCode = ($_voucher ? 'VOUCHER' : 'DEFAULT');
```